# How to add the type of image while saving into google storage

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

This code saves the images to google cloud storage:

```
        byte[] picByte = Base64.decodeBase64(pic);
        GcsFileOptions instance = GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance();
        GcsFilename fileName = new GcsFilename("xxx-app.appspot.com", "/gs/someName.jpg");
        GcsOutputChannel outputChannel;
        GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
        outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, instance);
        ByteBuffer a = ByteBuffer.wrap(picByte);
        outputChannel.write(a);
        outputChannel.close();
```

but this saves it without the type `image/jpeg` .
how to add it programmatically so that the image will be saved directly as image/jpeg?
Any help would be so much appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in GcsFileOptions. Try this:

```
GcsFileOptions instance = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("image/jpeg").build();
```

Comment: did you mean : GcsFileOptions instance = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("image/jpeg").build(); ?

Comment: Ah, yes, just so. Sorry!